How to build a path retracing "mower" bot?
I am trying to start a DIY robot mower project, similar to Clemens Elflein’s Open Mower, where he uses a remote control and GPS to have the robot learn a path and retrace it.
I was hoping to implement a tracking program where I set a specific real-world boundary and manually push the robot along a varied path and have it retrace its steps repeatedly on demand or on a cycle.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post ... your question right now is like how to build a race car? ... requiring a whole book to answer
